# Add class to <div> based on filename

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class

I'm looking for a solution to a workaround.  Right now the best workaround I've determined is to be able to add a class to an attachment on a wordpress page.  At the moment, Wordpress doesn't have any easy way to simply add a class for CSS styling later.

Currently when the HTML is generated, it wraps it in a div.  This is how it is generated (I think):

```
<?php   
   $bigsrc =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full'); 
   $zoom = $bigsrc[0];
   $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'post-thumb'); 
   $attachmenttitle = apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title); 
   $class = "media-image";
?>

<div class="item-photo <?php echo $class;?>">
```

Is there a way to add a class based on the filename?  I can easily rename the files "red-01.jpg" and "blue-01.jpg".  I'm hoping that there is some script that could output html as:

```
<div class="item-photo media-image red"><img src="red-01.jpg" /></div>
<div class="item-photo media-image blue"><img src="blue-01.jpg" /><div>
```

I have to use the Wordpress attachment method since the script I'm using for a project already calls for attachments to the page, and is pretty sophisticated.  If there was a simple class addition to Wordpress media uploads my problem would be solved.  Thanks a bagillion!

I'm completely open to any solutions...as long as I can add a class to the div as above!

Comment: What function are you using to display that image?

Comment: This might be better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, made an update to something I forgot to add!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
div class="item-photo <?php echo ($class." ".$src); ?>">
```

or $bigsrc, or whatever value is most useful in identifying the image (not sure what the values are)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `wp_get_attatchment_image()`, use `wp_get_attatchment_image_src()` and fill in the values yourself. Once you have the image source, you can just do a `substr_replace()` to get rid of the file extension and throw that into the class.